# How to upgrade entire account to Google Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a google analytics account with multiple properties. 3 of them have the Google Universal Code and 3 of them don't. I no longer have the option to transfer a property to GUA. The three I want to transfer are the most heavily used. I'm not sure how I get back the option to transfer once it's no longer available?

Is there another way to transfer a property?

Comment: Upgrade option should be there now, see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot transfer properties that use (or have used in the past) display features (like demographic reports). Google has announced to automatically transfer all properties to Universal Analytics as soon as display features and remarketing lists are available in UA. I do not think you can do anything except to wait.

**Edit to add:**
Google has just (3rd of April 2014) announced that UA is out of Beta. I have now an upgrade option in all Accounts, including those where the upgrade has not been available before. So the anwser above seems no longer valid (but you still need to upgrade on a per-property basis, you cannot upgrade accounts as asked in the title of the question).

Comment: Great thanks for the reply and quick update! I appreciate the information and I now see that option available as well.